# Решение задачи в С. УКАЗАТЕЛИ, СИМВОЛЬНЫЕ СТРОКИ И ФУНКЦИИ

Tags: c

Разработать функцию, которая разбивает строку на две части: до первого вхождения заданного символа и после него. При реализации функции запрещается пользоваться функциями библиотек языка C. 
Примечания:
1.  В большинстве заданий необходимо предусмотреть работу функции при некорректном задании ее параметров. 
2.  В тех заданиях, где применен термин "слово", под ним понимается любая последовательность символов, ограниченная любым числом пробелов и/или началом/концом строки.

Comment: Вы забыли написать вопрос, возникший у вас при решении этой задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Вам решение Вашей задачи без использование clib. с clib можно было просто дернуть memcpy ))

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* ptr;
    unsigned int size;  
} str_view;


typedef struct
{
    str_view str_1;
    str_view str_2; 
} two_str;


static char* GetNewSubStr(char* from, unsigned int size)
{
    char* ret;
    ret =  malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    assert(ret != NULL);

    unsigned int k = 0;

    while (k < size) {
        *(ret + k) = *(from + k);
        ++k;
    }

    ret[size] = '\0';

    return ret;
}


static two_str SeparateString(char* s, unsigned int size, char separator)
{
    two_str ret = { .str_1 = {.ptr = NULL, .size = 0}, .str_2 = {.ptr = NULL, .size = 0}};

    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == separator) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == size) {
        return ret;
    }

    ret.str_1.ptr = GetNewSubStr(s, i);
    ret.str_1.size = i;

    ret.str_2.ptr = GetNewSubStr(s + i, size - i);
    ret.str_2.size = size - i;

    return ret;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    unsigned int size = 10;
    char str[10] = "aaaaabbbbb";
    char separator = 'b';

    two_str res = SeparateString(str, size, separator);

    if (!res.str_1.ptr || !res.str_2.ptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("s1 : %s\n", res.str_1.ptr);
    printf("s2 : %s\n", res.str_2.ptr);

    free(res.str_1.ptr);
    free(res.str_2.ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ИЗВИНИТЕ, А МОЖНО ОБОЙТИСЬ БЕЗ КОМАНДЫ "STATIC" . И КОГДА ПРОГРАММА ЗАПУСКАЕТСЯ НУЖНО САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО ВВОДИТЬ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ, ДОПУСТИМ ДО БУКВЫ "T"

Comment: @Ирина Ну так поправите сами) и static это не команда. И помните, это сайт для помощи людям в поиске ответа, а не решения задачи за них.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы были правы,там оказывается ничего слишком сложного не было... Все поправила,то что бы нужно